# How to sync music library with Android?

Tags: android, sync, music

I found a few old threads about this, but none of them had any concise answers, so I guess I'll ask again. I have a feeling the answer may be no, but I'll ask anyway.

Is there any way to get a program like Banshee or Rhythmbox (or any similar Ubuntu program) to fully sync (I mean play counts, playlists, artwork, smart-playlists, etc) with an Android device?

The only reason I still occasionally boot into Windows is in order to use iTunes and iSyncr to perform this task with my Android devices.

If Ubuntu had a good music library app that could do a real, iTunes-like sync with Android, that would be really nice.

Just repeating again: I mean with playlists, play                                                                                                                          counts and everything like that.